# Dual boot with windows 10 (upgrade from Win 8.1 OEM)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, 15.04

I have dual booted my laptop with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 15.04. Windows came as a OEM with the laptop so I didn't delete it as I paid for it and I am not using it though. I want to know if I do the free upgrade to Windows 10 will it destroy my Ubuntu partitions? or will  it mess up anything in the boot files or grub?

Comment: Hopefully there won't be any problems the upgrade wont destroy i think.

Answer (score 5):

I just upgraded to Win 10 from Win 7, and the update manager did not bother on touching grub or other partitions. It just upgraded its own partition.

I used the Microsoft Media Creation Tool to upgrade. (I was impatient)

Comment: Thanks.  It's good to hear an actual experience report instead of speculation.

Comment: Was your ext4 partition primary or logical. Some users with Ubuntu installs in logical partiitons are finding Windows does not rewrite partition table including the ext4 logical partition. Testdisk or parted rescue is then needed to restore it. Some with UEFI installs find Windows turning secure boot back on.

Comment: I have two logical ext4 partitions

Answer (score 1):

I think the upgrade will surely replace GRUB and the windows bootloader will not recognize ubuntu so you will have to repair it by booting from ubuntu liveusb and running boot-repair tool. I don't think the ubuntu partition will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You Ubuntu install should not be affected, but you will need to reinstall GRUB by manually booting into Ubuntu using your BIOS boot menu, and running this command in Terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the free upgrade to Windows 10 last night on my dual boot laptop (I had windows 8.1/Ubuntu 15.04 working fine). Now, when I sign-in to windows the home screen appears, then disappears, then appears, then disappears with no way for me to select anything. I need to ctrl+alt+delete to get my computer to respond. The task manager works but nothing else. I think I need to wipe my entire drive. This sucks. By the way Ubuntu works fine.