# On a dual boot computer, will it harm Ubuntu installation if I upgrade Windows 8.1 to 10?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 15.04, windows-10

I currently dual boot my laptop with **Windows 8.1** and **Ubuntu 15.04**.

Now I want to give **Windows 10** a try, considering the positive reviews it has been garnering. But I don't want to mess my existing installation.

*Has somebody tried the same or can guide me about the consequences?*

Comment: **First backup all data/settings.** *In general Windows does not recognise other OS', so will NOT give specific (or clear) guidance to stop you doing anything stupid.* That said, it should allow you to just 'upgrade' the existing OS (using the same partition).

Comment: @david6 , So will it leave my Ubuntu boot partition intact?

Comment: See the following question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual boot with windows 10 (upgrade from Win 8.1 OEM)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/654251/dual-boot-with-windows-10-upgrade-from-win-8-1-oem)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading may mess with your grub so be prepared to do a boot repair. Otherwise it wont mess with your pre-existing partitions as windows doesn't
 even recognize the ext4 format.